# Monitoring a causal cluster's redundancy

Tags: neo4j

I'm on Neo4j 3.1.2. I'm trying to automate monitoring a causal cluster for proper redundancy, preferably over the http interface, dbms.cluster.overview being the most obvious call. But when they die, servers drop off this list without regard to how they exit. [The operations manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/clustering/causal-clustering/lifecycle/#_core_shutdown) says there is a difference between clean shutdowns and unclean ones. How do I figure out if a server left cleanly or uncleanly? Is there a procedure to clean up a unclean failure that's never coming back?

In general I would like to know the number of core servers Neo4j is checking for consensus. I don't see an API to find that number. That way I could tell how close to failure we are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected_core_cluster size setting is used when bootstrapping the cluster on first formation. A cluster will not form without the configured amount of cores and this should in general be configured to the full and fixed amount.

This setting is then also used as the minimum consensus group size. The consensus group size (core machines successfully voted into the raft) can shrink and grow dynamically but bounded on the lower end at this number.

The intention is in almost all cases for users to leave this setting alone. If you have 5 machines then you can survive failures down to 3 remaining, e.g. with 2 dead members. The three remaining can still vote another replacement member in successfully up to a total of 6 (2 of which are still dead) and then after this, one of the superfluous dead members will be immediately and automatically voted out (so you are left with 5 members in the consensus group, 1 of which is currently dead). Operationally you can now bring the last machine up by bringing in another replacement or repairing the dead one.

If the intention really is to bring the expected_core_cluster size down to 3 then today you will have to update the setting and do a rolling restart. This is considered an uncommon scenario. Causal clustering optimizes operationally for repair/replace.

The only difference between a clean and an unclean shutdown is that the former leads to a quicker discovery of a core member disappearing, since that is based on a timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although this does not match section 4.1.2.8 of the operations manual. Should I request that the OM be updated?